# Using uni_links when the app is in the background

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My application has the following structure:

```
- InheritedWidget for dependencies
--> Splash Screen Page
--> Login Pages
--> Main Pages
```

When the app runs for the first time, I can use `var link = await getInitialLink();` to get the value for the link that opened the app.

However, I cannot get the same result if I open the app on the background.

I tried to use

```
getLinksStream().listen((link) => (link) {
          try {
            var _latestUri;
            if (link != null) _latestUri = Uri.parse(link);
            print("=== Formated successfully a link!");
          } on FormatException {
            print("--- A link got here but was invalid");
          }
        });
```

For getting the link in the `Splash Screen`, but if the app is already open in the `Login` or `Main` pages, it won't go through the `Splash Screen` again.

Then, I tried to put it in the `InheritedWidget`, but alas, didn't get any result whatsoever.

So my question is: Where and how should I set up `uni_links` so that I can catch all incoming links even if the app is open?

Or better, is there an alternative for App Links/Universal Links that I can use?

Comment: How do you manage auth and anon routes? Do you have different navigators? If you do, then how do you open child routes from the different page?

Comment: Can you show an example of your app? Or if it's open sourced -> give a link, I would  appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's not the best and most elegant way, I got around this.

First, I was not using `getLinksStream` correctly

Instead of

```
(link) => (link) {...}
```

It's

```
(link) {...}
```

Then, I need to put this subscription in my `Splash Screen` and do not dispose of it, so that it can listen to new events.

If anybody has a better solution, please free to add it

Answer (score 2):

For this situation, you need to use both of getInitialUri() and getUriLinksStream(),
If app launchs directly u will get uri from getInitialUri, if app already running on background u will get uri from getUriLinksStream.

Comment: and how do you know whether the app is launching directly or if it was coming from the backgroud ?
(In flutter)