# Using uni_links 0.4.0 Not able redirect require page in flutter

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

when flutter app is running in back ground. i click on link present in my email, app is opening but not able to push the to next screen.
when is app is not running in back ground. i click on link present in my email, app is opening to push the to next screen.

I am using below package flutter app development

[uni_link](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/versions/0.4.0/example)

Answer (score 2):

If the app was terminated (or rather not running in the background) and the OS must start it anew - that's a cold start. In that case, `getInitialLink` will have the link that started your app and the Stream won't produce a link (at that point in time).

Alternatively - if the app was running in the background and the OS must bring it to the foreground the Stream will be the one to produce the link, while `getInitialLink` will be either null, or the initial link, with which the app was started.

Because of these two situations - you should always add a check for the initial link (or URI) and also subscribe for a Stream of links (or URIs).

[Read more about the implementation](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/versions/0.4.0#on-change-event-string)

Comment: hi @epynic i am facing the exactly same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037206/using-uni-links-when-the-app-is-in-the-background   i have added the `getInitialLink()` as well as `getLinksStream`